# Как делать адаптивный шаблон?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Как сделать адаптивный шаблон при увеличении масштаба блок с категориями скрывался, но отображался сдвигом слева при клике по кнопке??

Comment: Вам надо копать в сторону медиа запросов. @media screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эффект сдвигов можете написать сами, либо воспользоватся [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) либо методом jquery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
 function menu() {
   $('.menu').toggleClass('visible');
 }
```

```css
.menu-hamburger {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
    <li>menu4</li>
    <li>menu5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="menu-hamburger" onclick="menu()">
  x
</button>
```